# Webpack alias & config in Jest tests

Tags: testing, webpack, jestjs, webpack-2

I'm updating an older `Webpack2` project to `Webpack4` and switching the tests over to `Jest` but have a seemingly simple problem with a couple of the webpack related bits.

Specifically, the project structure for the troublesome bits look like this:

```
src
    - constants
        - index.js
    - config
        - base.js
        - test.js
        - dev.js
        - dist.js
```

During testing, the classes under test use `import config from 'config'` so issue number one is allowing them to find the right config file. With Webpack2 this is subbed in by webpack itself, but obviously not during Jest tests.

I can resolve this by hard coding the specific test config into the `moduleNameMapper` in the jest config in `package.json` like so:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^config$": "<rootDir>/src/config/test.js"
    }
}
```

This appears to work.

The second part of my issue is allowing Jest to find named exports `src/constants/index.js` using syntax like `import { SOME_CONST } from 'constants'`.

When I try to use `moduleNameMapper` I get back undefined from anything that uses the constants and I believe this is because `moduleNameMapper` is largely used to mock out dependencies rather than supply them.
With this in mind I think I need to use `modulePaths` or `moduleDirectories` to allow the `constants` to be located.

I've tried the following configurations (not simultaneously) without any luck:

```
"modulePaths": [
  "<rootDir>/src/constants",
  "src/constants"
],
"moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
  "src",
  "src/constants",
  "/src/constants"
  "/src/constants/",
  "./src/constants"
],
```

What should the correct config be for `Jest` to locate my constants?

If it's any help I'm trying to mimic this `Webpack2` config in `Jest`

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      constants: `${this.srcPathAbsolute}/constants/`
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey I am facing similar issue...did u find any solution?

Comment: @RujootaShah In the end I had to change my alias to `appconstants` and it worked,  I'm guessing `constants` is reserved in some way

Comment: I am not using constants or anything of that kind....I am just using simple stuff like 'xyz'....but still facing the issue....whats the version of webpack and jest you are using?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure quite what you mean here, could you post you own question and link to this question and me in the comments with an example of your config.

Comment: Sure....here it is...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266375/react-test-with-jest-does-not-honor-modulenamemapper-from-webpack-aliases