# React test with jest does not honor moduleNameMapper from webpack aliases

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, enzyme, blueprintjs

I am using jest and enzyme to test my react component. I am also using blueprint icons as one of the dependency in my react component.  As part of my webpack config, following is added:

```
config.resolve.alias = {
    blueprintIcons: path.resolve('./node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons'),
    blueprint: path.resolve('./node_modules/@blueprintjs/core')
};
```

Following is added as part of jest config:

```
    rootDir: '.',
    roots: [
        '<rootDir>/__test__/'
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/'
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.jsx?$',
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js',
        'jsx',
        'json',
        'node'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        blueprintIcons: '<rootDir>/node_modules/@blueprintjs/core'
        blueprint: '<rootDir>/node_modules/@blueprintjs/core'
    },
    snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer']
};
```

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from 'blueprint';
import IconNames from 'blueprintIcons';
class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
           <p>Hello Foo</p>
           <Icon icon={IconNames.HOME} iconSize={Icon.SIZE_LARGE}/>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
export default Foo;
```

Here is my foo.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Foo from '../../src/Components/Foo';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme, { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Reviews component', () => {
    it('render component when loading in progress', () => {
        const mountedComponent = mount(<Foo />);
    });
});
```

When I am trying to test that component, the test fails with

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'HOME' of undefined at IconNames.HOME

Here are some packages specified in my package.json

```
"babel-cli": "6.26.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
"babel-loader": "7.1.4",
"enzyme": "^3.9.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
"jest": "^23.1.0",
"jest-html-reporter": "^2.3.0",
"@blueprintjs/core": "^2.3.1",
"react": "16.2.0"
```

I am using react 16.2.0

I tried mocking it but doesn't work(maybe I am not doing it correctly) but here is the code which I am using:

```
jest.mock('@blueprintjs/icons', () => (
    { IconNames: {HOME: 'home' }}));
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the following solution worked:

In jest config:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
        '^blueprint': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@blueprintjs/core',
        '^@blueprintjs/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@blueprintjs/$1'
}
```

Rest everything remained the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think mocking is a possible solution - Not sure exactly why your code is not working (possibly because it's not within the `default` key, or the name of the mock is incorrect), but you can try something else.

1. In your Jest config, add the following:

```
"setupFiles": [
    "./__mocks__/mockIcons.js"
],
```

2. Create `/__mocks__` folder in your root folder
3. Create `mockIcons.js` inside `__mocks__` with the following code:

```
jest.mock("blueprint", () => ({
    default: {
        Icon: { SIZE_LARGE: 'large' }
    }
}))

jest.mock("blueprintIcons", () => ({
    default: {
        IconNames: { HOME: 'home' }
    }
}))
```

Try to use `@blueprintjs/icons` as the mock name if nothing else works.

Comment: You can, of course, keep your initial setup and try to use the `default` key and/or change the names of the mocks.